# Listview ripple effect on android

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want disable ripple effect when tapping on a item of a `ListView`.
I use nativescript 6 on vue. I have disabled correctly selection color for IOS but for android I'm facing this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `loaded` event on ListView and run this code,

```
onLoaded: function(args) {
 if (args.object.android) {
    args.object.android.setSelector(new android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable());
 }
}
```